# Passing a value from a dropdown item

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown menu. Each entry has an ID and a value. Clicking on an item on the list calls the click-handler and passes the div. The click handler can access the id, but it doesn't work for the value.

When I log the parameter that is passed to the event handler, it shows this string:

```
<div class="dropdown-item" id="chooseLeagueLevelDD" value="0" onmouseup="mUp(this)">1. Bundesliga</div>
```

I am able to determine the event using the event handler. If I log obj.id, the correct string is displayed. If I try to log `obj.value`, it's `undefined`.

```
function mUp(obj) {
        if (obj.id == "pauseGame"){
                pauseGame();
        }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `div` elements don't have a `value` attribute or property. Your HTML is invalid. To obtain the contents of the `div` use `.textContent`. If you want to store custom data that isn't displayed use a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

div doesn't have a native value property or attribute, adding a value attribute to the html is basically adding a custom attribute so you will need to treat it as such. If you use the getAttribute() method on the event parameter you should be able to get your data.

```
function mUp(obj) {
        if (obj.getAttribute('value') == "pauseGame"){
            pauseGame();
       }
}
```

Comment: *adding a value attribute to the html is basically adding a custom attribute so you will need to treat it as such* <-- No, not really. It's creating invalid code. Use `data-*` attributes for custom attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```js
function mUp(obj) {
        console.log(obj.attributes.value.nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: Only attributes have a `nodeValue` but `div` elements don't have a `value` attribute, so the HTML is wrong.